# Resetting SYSTEM password on Oracle DB 12.1

Tags: oracle, passwords, system, oracle12c, recovery

I'm trying to recover a lost SYSTEM password on a Oracle DB (12.1) installation.
The database runs on a Linux machine and I've access to the linux user 'oracle' that's the user that runs the database.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At operating system prompt:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
```

Once you're connected:

```
alter user system identified by new_password;
```